# Keys in NSDictionary can be duplicated?

Tags: objective-c, cocoa, nsdictionary

From what I have read, keys in dictionaries are unique.

Consider this code:

```
NSMutableDictionary *mydic = [NSMutableDictionary dictionary];

[mydic setObject:@"value1" forKey:@"key1"]; 
[mydic setObject:@"value1" forKey:@"key1"];
[mydic setObject:@"value1" forKey:@"key1"];
```

Why can I run this without any error? What should I do to avoid duplicate keys?

Answer (score 24, accepted):

Yes keys are unique. Calling `-setObject:forKey:` with an existing key *overrides* the old value — it *sets* values, not *adds* values. You can check that:

```
[mydict setObject:@"1" forKey:@"key1"];
[mydict setObject:@"2" forKey:@"key1"];
NSLog(@"%@", mydict);
```

If you don't want existing items to be overridden, check if it exists with `-objectForKey:`:

```
@implementation NSMutableDictionary (AddItem)
-(void)addObjectWithoutReplacing:(id)obj forKey:(id)key {
   if ([self objectForKey:key] == nil)
      [self setObject:obj forKey:key];
}
@end
```

Comment: thanks kenny, but i don't know if you got what i meant exactly or not,  here i say again. imagine i have list of URLs which i want to save,but i do not want to save a link twice! so i am going to use a hash table which is NSDictionary in objective c, in the example that i mentioned above its is saving the same keys(duplicate) in a dictionary, why is that ?

Comment: @saleh: What do you mean? What are the keys and values?

Comment: dont need value, just wanna fill the keys fields with unique input.

Comment: @saleh: Don't use NSMutableDictionary if you don't use values. Make an NSMutableSet instead.