# Mantle - MTLJSONSerializing two value for the same propertie

Tags: ios, github-mantle

I call an api which can have differents interface for the same value "id" : "id", "_id" or "pId".

But currently, it's works for only the first :  @"id": @"_id". the other are ignored.

JSON

```
 object:{ "pId" : 192039,
         "name" : "test}
```

IOS WHICH WORKS: self.id = 192039

```
+ (NSDictionary *)JSONKeyPathsByPropertyKey {
    return @{
             @"id": @"pId",
             @"id": @"_id",
             @"id": @"id",
             @"title": @"name",
            };
}
```

IOS WHICH NOT WORKS: self.id =

```
+ (NSDictionary *)JSONKeyPathsByPropertyKey {
    return @{

             @"id": @"_id",
             @"id": @"id",
             @"id": @"pId",
             @"title": @"name",
            };
}
```

**EDIT**

Keys in a dictionary must be unique....

The only solution I found is to create 3 differents properties and override setters like that:

```
+ (NSDictionary *)JSONKeyPathsByPropertyKey {
    return @{
             @"pId": @"pId",
             @"id2": @"_id",
             @"id": @"id",
             @"title": @"name",
            };
}

- (void) setPid:(NSString *)pId
{
    _id = pId;
}

- (void) setId2:(NSString *)id2
{
    _id = id2;
}
```

Comment: Likely because keys in a dictionary must be unique: http://stackoverflow.com/a/6807972/620197

Comment: You've constructed invalid dictionaries above.  The keys must be unique.

Comment: And why do you have two different methods setting the same ivar??

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Keys in a dictionary must be unique....

The only solution I found is to create 3 differents properties and override setters like that:

```
+ (NSDictionary *)JSONKeyPathsByPropertyKey {
    return @{
             @"pId": @"pId",
             @"id2": @"_id",
             @"id": @"id",
             @"title": @"name",
            };
}

- (void) setPid:(NSString *)pId
{
    _id = pId;
}

- (void) setId2:(NSString *)id2
{
    _id = id2;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

you cannot repeat te key

```
@{key:value,...}
```

you can try other thing like this

```
return @{
     @"id" : @[@"_id",@"id",@"pId"],
     @"title" : @"name"
   };
```

or adding a prefix to @"id" keys like @"id1